# A balloon always appears in the gnome indicator asking me to update

Tags: gnome

I am on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Right after I turn on Ubuntu, a red warning like icon appears in the gnome indicator which tells

> The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network
>   problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update
>   manually by selecting 'Show updates' from the indicator menu, and
>   watching for any failing repositories.

I clicked on Show updates. It just tells me Everything is up to date. Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating from the command line:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade
```

This should resolve your problems.

You can also try to get rid of old packages you don't need:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Finally, check out your apt sources and see if you maybe need to re-add any old PPAs from your last installation.